# How to fetch user defined device name from ipad, IOS version should greater than 16 in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

right now i am using method channel for fetch IOS device name in flutter, that a user given by in the about section. it is perfectly working in below IOS version 16 ipad's only. But i need to work this also  above IOS version 16+ ipad's.

this is how I read the device name using method channel in flutter.

**Swift code written for fetch iPad device name**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // Register Flutter plugins
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        // Set up a platform channel to fetch device name
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let deviceInfoChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "device_info", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        deviceInfoChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
            guard call.method == "getDeviceName" else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                return
            }
            let deviceName = self?.getCustomDeviceName()
            result(deviceName)
        })

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func getCustomDeviceName() -> String {
        var deviceName: String?

        // Fetch device name from UserDefaults
        if let deviceNameValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DeviceName") {
            deviceName = deviceNameValue
        }

        // If device name not found in UserDefaults, use the default device name
        if deviceName == nil || deviceName!.isEmpty {
            deviceName = UIDevice.current.name
        }

        return deviceName!
    }
}
```

**This is the Flutter code for fetch iPad device name**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'package:device_id/service/device_name_finder.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var actualDeviceName = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    findDeviceName();
    // readIos();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Device Name : $actualDeviceName',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      findDeviceName();
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text('Check Device'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> findDeviceName() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      actualDeviceName = (await AndroidDeviceInformation.getDeviceName())!;
      setState(() {});
      log("The Device name is $actualDeviceName");
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      actualDeviceName = (await IosDeviceInformation.getDeviceName())!;
      setState(() {});
      log("The Device name is $actualDeviceName");
    }
  }
}
```

**Also I created a separate class for manage the method channel**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class IosDeviceInformation {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('device_info');

  static Future<String?> getDeviceName() async {
    try {
      return await _channel.invokeMethod('getDeviceName');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get device name: '${e.message}'.");
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class AndroidDeviceInformation {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('android_device_info');

  static Future<String?> getDeviceName() async {
    try {
      return await _channel.invokeMethod('getDeviceName');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to get device name: '${e.message}'.");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

How i can working this solution on 16+ iPad devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 16 and later, the actual device name is [not available without a special entitlement from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_device-information_user-assigned-device-name). This is for privacy reasons. If you meet all of the requirements then you can apply for the entitlement.

Without this entitlement you will get a generic value such as "iPad". If you have the entitlement then you will get the actual device name as you did on earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: I checked the special entitlement documentation. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();


 IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
  print('Running on ${iosInfo.systemName}');
```

first add `device_info_plus` in pubsec.yml